# I read that when you declare two vectors the statement b=a doesn't have the effect we want. But I write a mini program and it works

Tags: java

I declare two vectors

```
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
  int b[] =  new int[4];
```

And I read that if you want to copy the elements from a to b the statement b=a doesn't do that. But when I compile the code below it does copy the elements from a to b and outputs 1,2,3,4.

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
   int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
   int b[]=new int[4];
    b=a;
    for(int i=0; i< b.length; i++){
        System.out.println(b[i]);
       }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't create a copy. After `b=a;`, both `a` and `b` a referring to the same array object. a[0]=5 will cause b[0] to be 5 too.

Comment: For copying use-  System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, 4); instaed of b=a;

Answer (score 1):

An array is simply a list of references to certain objects. So in the following code:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
int[] b = a;
```

The references to each int value are copied. If that reference happens to be an instance of a class and a variable whithin that class would change, it would change in both arrays.

In order to create a completely seperate array use the following:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
int[] b = a.clone();
```